# Misaligned search box in chat

Tags: bug, chat, design

These things are hard to search for on Meta, but I don't see a duplicate question.  When my browser is at a comfortable window size for me I get the following misalignment:

[image]

But if I make my window a bit bigger it's fine:

[image]

I measured the size of the viewable area in my browser and it was over 1,000 pixels when I notice the misalignment, which doesn't seem too tiny to me.  Even if it is too small, I think the alignment could fail more gracefully.

I'm using Chrome and this is [the chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2567/eschewmenical-blog-room) I noticed it on, for what it's worth.

Comment: I notice it too, using Safari 5.1.3. I am not sure it's a bug, thought. The elements shown in the right side are moved to be entirely visible in the page; this happens to the star to set the chat room as favorite, to the image associated with the parent Stack Exchange site, and to the feed icon.

Comment: able to reproduce this still? :)